# Null Propagation

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When the linq query condition is not met, I'd expect a null to be returned from `questions.FirstOrDefault()` - but instead, an exception

> Sequence contains no matching element

is thrown. Any ideas why?

```
var firstQ = questions.FirstOrDefault(a =>
      a.Answers.Single(x => x.CourseAssignmentId == 
     courseAssignmentId)?.Score == null) ?? questions.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Because `Single` throws if it does not find a matching element. Maybe you're looking for `SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `Single()`?  Specifically look at the **Remarks** section...

Comment: Note that `SingleOrDefault` will also throw if there is more than one item.  It only returns the default when the sequence is empty, which in your case sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's the difference between `Single` and `SingleOrDefault`.

`Single` throws an exception if there's any number of items different than **1** that match your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `FirstOrDefault()` instead. BTW you can combine the condition probably like

```
a.Answers.Single(x => x.CourseAssignmentId == courseAssignmentId && x.Score == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, it's the expected behavior of `Enumerable.Single`.

Anyway, it looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Probably you should store the last scored question somewhere (e.g a dictionary).

That is, you could refactor your code as follows:

```
var assignmentScoredQuestionMap = new Dictionary<int, Question>();
// Fill the whole dictionary:
// You need to add for which assignment identifier you've answered a question

int assignmentId = 384;

// If the whole assignment exists, you set lastScoredQuestion, otherwise
// you set it to first question.
if(!assignmentScoredQuestionMap.TryGetValue(assignmentId, out var lastScoredQuestion)) 
   lastScoredQuestion = questions.FirstOrDefault();
```